# Devise a method for constructing a table of knots, and use it to find $10$ knots of not more than $6$ crossings.

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Devise a method for constructing a table of knots, and use it to find $10$ knots of not more than $6$ crossings (do not consider the question of whether these are really distinct types.)

Could anyone give me a hint for answering this question, please?

Comment: What have you tried?  What didn't seem to work about that?

Comment: I am trying to read the book by myself ..... so I am still a beginner @KyleMiller

Comment: Here's a hint for how to begin to answer questions like this: take the time to mess around and draw knots.  You might even learn more than what the question suggests on its surface.  At some point, pay special attention to whether or not you think you could draw *all* knots with at most 6 crossings.  If 6 seems too big for now, start with a smaller number, like 3 or 4.

Comment: But how can I devise a method ..... I do not know ...... it is still difficult for me @KyleMiller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have to pay attention to potentially constructing equivalent knots, you can just do that by the number of total crossings. Start with $0$ crossings, i.e the unknot. Then you can add one crossing etc. Once you have some knots you can also use mirror images to get more. That actually also leads to non-equivalent knots as for the tre-foil knot.

Comment: you mean the tre-foil knot and its mirror image are not equivalent?

Comment: Is there a knot with 2 crossings?

Comment: All depends on the definition of equivalence. In the usual sense these are not equivalent. Just check the wikipedia page for chiral knots. These are the knots that are not equivalent to their mirror image. Yes, but no non-trivial one. But that does not matter here.

Answer (score 1):

The unknot gives you one knot to start with. Now use the process shown below to construct knots with $\geq 3$ crossings.

[image]

Up to six crossings, this gives four more knots (because the first valid knot using the method is the trefoil. Now consider the mirror images of the knots constructed above; this gives another four. We now have nine knots in our table.

Since we don't care about equivalence, one could perhaps change the diagram a little so there are two crossings at the top, as opposed to one, and add crossings to the bottom as before. Since you only need ten knots, we'd only have to do this once.

Comment: Can you describe this process ...... is it just twisting?

Comment: Yes, you add two "twists" at the bottom for the trefoil and then carry on adding them for knots with higher crossing numbers. Note that all the resulting knots are non-equivalent.