# Show that the number of tame knot types is at most countable.

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Show that the number of tame knot types is at most countable.

I want a hint for solving this problem please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Tame knots are represented by finite closed chains of polygons (Whether this is a hint depends on your defintion of tame knots though).

Comment: Could you please look at this question when you have time ?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275844/devise-a-method-for-constructing-a-table-of-knots-and-use-it-to-find-10-knots

Comment: Our definition of a tame knot is: a knot is tame if it is equivalent to a polygonal knot.

Comment: and a polygonal knot is one which is the union of a finite number of closed straight-line segments called edges, whose endpoints are the vertices of the knot....... so how can I show that the number is at most countable?

Comment: For each number of line segments you have finitely many combinations. And thus finitely many tame knots. As countable unions of countable sets are countable there can be at most countably many tame knots.